# Array index out of bounds except error in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read in a CSV file and keep getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>         at dataExpert.Control.main(Control.java:22)

I've tried the following:

```
String split_by = ",";
BufferedReader buff_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file path"));
String line;

while((line = buff_reader.readLine()) != null){
  if(line.contains(",")){
      String[] b = line.split(split_by);
       System.out.println(b[0]);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us which line *is* line 22?

Comment: Could be an issue of a blank line at the end of the CSV file, which when split with `","` would result in nothing being returned. So just make sure that the element in the array exists before trying to use it.

Comment: @ostrichofevil, line 22 is   System.out.println(b[0]);

Comment: This kind of issue indicates that you should learn how to use debugger. Download any modern IDE, watch a short video on how to use debugger, and soon enough you'll be able to troubleshoot such code in a few minutes without any external help.

Comment: @AlecC Splitting a blank string wouldn't return an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely caused by a row with only commas. When you call [`split(",")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), trailing empty strings are discarded, which leaves you with an empty array. One solution is to call [`split(",", -1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), which preserves trailing empty strings.